# Implementing Facebook login with UiLifecycleHelper

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have `MainActivity` and a `LoginActivity`. I created a super class `FacebookActivity` to keep the `UiLifecycleHelper` object and all of the overriding methods:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FacebookActivity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity** (basically a splash screen with facebook login button):

```
public class LoginActivity extends FacebookActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
    }

}
```

**FacebookActivity** to implement all of the UiLifecycle methods :

```
public class FacebookActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    public FacebookActivity() {
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(Consts.TAG, "Logged in...");
            setCookies();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(Consts.TAG, "Logged out...");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it would be a good idea that all activity classes would inherit from `FacebookActivity` this way I will have one code that handles all of the session management.

Unfortunately this doesn't work very well, one example is when I log out through `MainActivity` I get a loop :

1. `onSessionStateChange` event listener fires up since I cleared the session
2. `LoginActivity` is started
3. `FacebookActivity.onCreate()` is called from `LoginActivity.onCreate()`
4. `onSessionStateChange` is called again and go back to 2

I don't exactly know what events trigger the `Session.StatusCallback` listener, and I don't understand whats wrong with my approach.

Any other way to approach this ?

Comment: what is SherlockFragmentActivity?

Comment: @BSThakrar It's part of the widely used ActionBar support package for lower level APIs: "When creating an activity to use the action bar on all versions of Android, you must declare your activity to extend any of the activity classes that start with 'Sherlock'". I use it for Android 2.2+, works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UiLifecycleHelper` obviously does a lot of things related to the `Session` class.
This is a part of the `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(activity, null, callback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(activity);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }

    [...]
}
```

The session change, so the `Session.StatusCallback` is called every time.. causing your infinite loop.

Comment: will this onCreate be for the Facebook class or for each implemented activities onCreate? Thanks!

Comment: Each activity of course. You don't have to implement the Facebook class.

Comment: Thanks, would I add this to my activity that I started once logged out from another activity so that the session is wiped and renewed?

Comment: This is put in each activity if you use the UiLifecycleHelper (one for each activity). You don't have to add explicitly this code to your activity. You can use the same session instance between activities, but if you don't use the helper you have to be careful to things like the callbacks.